# Kotlin generic type parameter mismatch: infered type is 'non-null' but 'nullable' was expected

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have data wrapper class with parameter T. There is `function` in this class with *generic* container with `nullable` type: T? (e.g. LiveData< T?>)

```
class Wrapper<T> {
   fun add (data: LiveData<T?>) {
    // ...
   }
}
```

In this place I really need just such type.
When I try to use this method and pass non-null type parameter:

```
class Program {
   fun get() {
      // some generic container, e.g. LiveData
      val data: LiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
      val wrapper = Wrapper<Int>()
      wrapper.add(data)
                  ^^^^ error
   }
}
```

it was 'Type mismatch' error: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEklB.png)

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is LiveData<Int> but LiveData<Int?> was expected
```

How to deal with it? How smart cast generic type parameter from non-null to nullable?

Comment: Why you need it's parameter _type_ to be nullable? Couldn't that be the `data` you're passing to add function?

Comment: @noiaverbale for LiveData which can return nullable values for example when using Android Room library and trying to find entity by id that does not exist, DAO method returns LiveData with null value

Comment: In this case (if `data` contains nullable integers), shouldn't be data declared as `val data: LiveData<Int?>`? That would solve the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an error related to [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance): `LiveData<Int?>` can only be a subtype of `LiveData<Int>` if you make `T` an `out` variable:

```
class LiveData<out T>
```

> The general rule is: when a type parameter `T` of a class `C` is
>   declared out, it may occur only in out-position in the members of `C`,
>   but in return `C<Base>` can safely be a supertype of `C<Derived>`.
>
> In "clever words" they say that the class `C` is covariant in the
>   parameter `T`, or that `T` is a covariant type parameter. You can
>   think of `C` as being a producer of `T`'s, and NOT a consumer of
>   `T`'s.

But it's even better to simply change the `add` signature to accept `LiveData<T>` unless this is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You may fix the `Wrapper` class declaration to the following

```
class Wrapper<T> {
   fun add (data: LiveData<T>) {
    // ...
   }
```

I replaced the `T?` with `T` in the `LiveData` type parameter. So that you may have both `Wrapper<Int>` and `Wrapper<Int?>` types.

Kotlin tells nullable types (e.g. `Int?`) from non-nullable types, e.g. `Int`. You may check the article for more details: 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

The second option is suggested in the previous answer to use variance. It may not be possible to use for some implementations of `LiveData` class/interface.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html